# Text field to uppercase, BUT sentence case placeholder?

Tags: javascript, css, uppercase

I have a text field for inserting a postal code and I wanted the user's input to be uppercase for uniformity. I found a simple solution to just do `text-transform: uppercase;` however that also makes my placeholder in uppercase. Seems silly, but is there a way around this? Should I use javascript instead?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/21qp8vxn/)

Comment: welcome to "The rest of the world", @wumm =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Okay, so they aren't.

Comment: Nono, they are letters and numbers. I'm in Canada lol

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: It should be noted that this is really easy to do with javascript as well -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/f9g7zg9s/1/**

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful responses :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work (in this example the class `postalcode` is applied to the postal code field):

```
.postalcode::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: none;
}

.postalcode:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-transform: none; 
}

.postalcode::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-transform: none;
}

.postalcode:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-transform: none;  
}

.postalcode {
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

See this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/u77z50db/1/

Comment: May want to check browser support, caniuse.com - not sure if there are any incompatibilities.

Comment: browser support is [**spotty**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css), and a final standard for this is not yet implented, so who knows what the future brings.